# Find name of selected option using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've made a jquery/ajax function that updates #courses, sending #fos's .val() and .text(), specifically of the one that is selected, like so:

```
$('#selling #fos').change(function() {
    $.post('/ajax/courses',
        {
            fos_id: $('#selling #fos').val(),
            name: $('#selling #fos :selected').text()
        },
    function(data) {
        $('#selling #courses').html(data);
    });
});
```

How do I extend this function so that it uses 'this', allowing me to reuse this function multiple times on the same page? I'm caught because you can't use `name: $(this + ' :selected').text()`.

Comment: Thanks Stefanvds! I found it out after some hard researching... shoulda came back sooner. Looks like I used your second example! $(this).find(":selected").text()

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#"+$(this).attr("id")+" :selected")
```

it's not pretty but it does the trick :)

or this will work:

```
$(this).find(":selected").text()
```

Comment: Using attr("id") is no different in efficiency to specifying the id directly into the code.

Comment: The example with `find` is fine. Much better than messing around with IDs (will fail if `this` doesn't have an ID, or has an ID with `.` or `:` characters in)

Comment: Ahh I didn't see that Brett had a space before ":selected" which means he is looking for a child.. then yes find() will work fine. I changed my vote!!

Comment: The second one is find, and in fact should be the correct answer.

Comment: this does not get the name of the option,but it;s value only.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
name: $(this).filter(':selected').text()
```

It will return empty string if it's not selected

Good luck!

**Edit**:

I didn't see that Brett had a space before ":selected" which means he is looking for a child. Stefanvds suggestion to use find() will work fine. 
filter() checks if the current dom is ":selected" while find() is going to look for the children on all levels. You could also use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) if you know that the selected dom you are looking for is a direct child of "this" as it is a lot more efficient since you are only looking for one level of children.

```
name: $(this).children(':selected').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Without jQuery

It's pretty simple to do this without jQuery. Inside of a `change` event listener, the selected option can be accessed using `this.options[this.selectedIndex]`. From there, you can access the `value`/`text` properties of the selected option element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mneedxkj/)

```
var select = document.querySelector('#select');

select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

    console.log(selectedOption.value);
});
```

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#select');

select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    
    alert(selectedOption.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've moved away from using jQuery since I wrote this question, so I appreciate you writing the vanilla-JS answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery's second argument (context) to avoid the unnecessary "filter", "find", "children" etc. This allows your selector to be something like:

```
$('select[name="myselect"]').on('change',function(){
    var selectedOptionName = $('option:selected',this).text();
    console.log(selectedOptionName);
});
```