# jQuery get the name of a select option

Tags: jquery, hide, attr

I have a dropdown list with several option, each option has a name attribute. When I select an option, a different list of checkboxes needs to appear - when another options is selected, that checkbox list should disappear and another one be displayed.

I have created these checkbox lists and given them an ID that correlates to the name attribute of the option selected. I am trying to use the following code to display the correct checkbox list

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $('#band_type_choices').on('change', function() {         
    $('.checkboxlist').hide();
    $('#checkboxlist_' + $(this).attr("name") ).css("display", "block");

});
```

However nothing is happening.

Here is my dropdown options:

```
<select id="band_type_choices">
    <option vlaue="0"></option>
    <option value="100" name="acoustic">Acoustic</option>
    <option value="0" name="jazz">Jazz/Easy Listening</option>
    <option value="0" name="acoustic_jazz">Acoustic + Jazz/Easy Listening</option>
    <option value="0" name="party">Party</option>
    <option value="0" name="acoustic_party">Acoustic + Party</option>
    <option value="0" name="jazz_party">Jazz/Easy Listening + Party</option>
    <option value="0" name="acoustic_jazz_party">Acoustic + Jazz/Easy Listening + Party</option>
 </select>
```

and an example of one of the lists:

```
<div class="checkboxlist" id="checkboxlist_acoustic" style="display:none;">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox keys" name="keys" value="100" />Keys<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox acou_guit" name="acou_guit" value="100" />Acoustic Guitar<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox drums" name="drums" value="100" />Drums<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox alt_sax" name="alt_sax" value="100" />Alto Sax<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox ten_sax" name="ten_sax" value="100" />Tenor Sax<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox clarinet" name="clarinet" value="100" />Clarinet<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox trombone" name="trombone" value="100" />Trombone<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox trumpet" name="trumpet" value="100" />Trumpet<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox flute" name="flute" value="100" />Flute<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox cello" name="cello" value="100" />Cello<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox violin" name="violin" value="100" />Violin<br>
</div>
```

Comment: That is invalid html. There is no name attribute on a select

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your code`this` refers to the select element not to the selected option

to refer the selected option you can do this -

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr("name");
```

Comment: use `.text();` instead of `.attr("name");` to get the text of selected option as asked in question

Answer (score 71):

For anyone who comes across this late, like me.

As others have stated, *name* isn't a valid attribute of an *option* element.  Combining the accepted answer above with the [answer from this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742378/find-name-of-selected-option-using-jquery), you get:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 7):

The Code is very Simple, Lets Put This Code

```
var name = $("#band_type_choices  option:selected").text();
```

Here You don't want to use `$(this).find().text()`, directly you can put your id name and add 
`option:selected` along with `text()`.

This will return the result option name. Better Try this...

Comment: This is exatly what i wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly `name` isn't a valid attribute of an `option` element. Instead you could use a `data` parameter, like this:

```
<option value="foo" data-name="bar">Foo Bar</option>
```

The main issue you have is that the JS is looking at the `name` attribute of the `select` element, not the chosen option. Try this:

```
$('#band_type_choices').on('change', function() {         
    $('.checkboxlist').hide();
    $('#checkboxlist_' + $('option:selected', this).data("name")).css("display", "block");
});
```

Note the `option:selected` selector within the context of the `select` which raised the change event.

Comment: This is a valid and good answer. If there are better ways, then go ahead ...

Comment: @tonygil I have absolutely no idea what your comment is rambling about. It makes no sense whatsoever. I can only presume you're replying to a comment before your which was deleted?

Answer (score 5):

```
 $(this).attr("name")
```

means the name of the select tag not option name.

To get option name

```
 $("#band_type_choices option:selected").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using name on a select option is not valid.

Other have suggested the data- attribute, an alternative is a lookup table

Here the "this" refers to the select so no need to "find" the option

```js
var names = ["", "acoustic", "jazz", "acoustic_jazz", "party", "acoustic_party", "jazz_party", "acoustic_jazz_party"];

$(function() {
  $('#band_type_choices').on('change', function() {
    $('.checkboxlist').hide();
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;
    if (idx > 0) $('#checkboxlist_' + names[idx]).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.checkboxlist { display:none }
```

```html
Choose acoustic to see the corresponding div

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="band_type_choices">
  <option vlaue="0"></option>
  <option value="100" name="acoustic">Acoustic</option>
  <option value="0" name="jazz">Jazz/Easy Listening</option>
  <option value="0" name="acoustic_jazz">Acoustic + Jazz/Easy Listening</option>
  <option value="0" name="party">Party</option>
  <option value="0" name="acoustic_party">Acoustic + Party</option>
  <option value="0" name="jazz_party">Jazz/Easy Listening + Party</option>
  <option value="0" name="acoustic_jazz_party">Acoustic + Jazz/Easy Listening + Party</option>
</select>
<div class="checkboxlist" id="checkboxlist_acoustic">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox keys" name="keys" value="100" />Keys<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox acou_guit" name="acou_guit" value="100" />Acoustic Guitar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox drums" name="drums" value="100" />Drums<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox alt_sax" name="alt_sax" value="100" />Alto Sax<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox ten_sax" name="ten_sax" value="100" />Tenor Sax<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox clarinet" name="clarinet" value="100" />Clarinet<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox trombone" name="trombone" value="100" />Trombone<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox trumpet" name="trumpet" value="100" />Trumpet<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox flute" name="flute" value="100" />Flute<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox cello" name="cello" value="100" />Cello<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox violin" name="violin" value="100" />Violin<br>
</div>
```