# how to take the name attribute (not value), then transfer it to text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move the name attribute, to be a hidden value (not id), but ... stored in the database that is still id

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <select name="id_cs" id="pakyu" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" onchange="ganti();">
        <option value="0">-PILIH-</option>
        <?php foreach($datacs->result() as $row):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id_cs;?>"><?php echo $row->nama_cs;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>

        <input type="hidden" id="csnya" name="nama_cs">
    </select>
</div>
```

jquery

```
function ganti() {
    var reg = $('#pakyu option:selected').val();
    $('#csnya').val(reg);
}
```

Comment: what is `reg` here? I do not see it in your PHP/HTML code.

Comment: You should move your hidden input to be before or after the select, not inside of it. I also don't really understand what you're trying to do and what the issue is? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate [jQuery get the name of a select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697843/jquery-get-the-name-of-a-select-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some changes like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <select name="id_cs" id="pakyu" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" onchange="ganti();">
        <option value="0">-PILIH-</option>
        <?php foreach($datacs->result() as $row):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id_cs;?>"><?php echo $row->nama_cs;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="csnya" name="nama_cs" value=""> <!--moved this out from select tag -->
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function ganti() {
    var reg = $('#pakyu option:selected').text();  // Use text function
    $('#csnya').val(reg);
}
```